# Snowflake automatic clustering

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table with 12 billion rows. I first loaded the data and then added a clustering key. Now that manual clustering is deprecated. How long will it take to automatically recluster the whole table?

Comment: you can "manually cluster it" by creating a new table (that replaces the existing) but sorting the with an ORDER BY cluster keys. depending on the writes to the table it can be orders of magnitude faster than the automatic clustering and cost equaling magnitude less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duration cannot be forecasted, but you can check the progress.
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/automatic_clustering_history#syntax

From the Snowflake docs,

You can use SQL to view whether Automatic Clustering is enabled for a table:

SHOW TABLES command.

TABLES view (in the Snowflake Information Schema).

TABLES view (in the Account Usage shared database).

The AUTO_CLUSTERING_ON column in the output displays the Automatic Clustering status for each table, which can be used to determine whether to suspend or resume Automatic Clustering for a given table.

In addition, the CLUSTER_BY column (SHOW TABLES) or CLUSTERING_KEY column (TABLES view) displays the column(s) defined as the clustering key(s) for each table.
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-auto-reclustering#viewing-the-automatic-clustering-status-for-a-table